# Automating website forms using Haskell

Tags: haskell, webautomation

Are there some nice libraries (and if so, what are they) for automating website queries using Haskell.

Basically I want to get a form, fill in some values and get the results (and naturally, do this repeatedly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you're looking for a web scraper or just a way to make GET/POST requests. In the latter case, there's [Network.HTTP](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HTTP/4000.0.9/doc/html/Network-HTTP.html), or the [Haskell `libcurl` bindings](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Network.Curl). In the former, you could look into [HandsomeSoup](https://github.com/egonSchiele/HandsomeSoup), or one of the other [HTML parsing libraries](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Web/Libraries/XML_and_HTML) (I've never actually used these myself, so I can't recommend a specific one).

Comment: A good tool would be a level higher: it would allow you to use a notion of form, detecting all forms on a page, filling and submitting a form, without resorting to raw HTML parsing and constructing POST parameters by hand.

Comment: @9000 - Got one in mind?

Comment: [Perl Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) and [Python Spynner](https://code.google.com/p/spynner/) are examples in other languages.